# In VB6, how can I use the 'LB_SETTABSTOPS' API call to set the tabstops in a CheckedListbox control..?

Tags: vb6

I have successfully used the following API call to set the tab stops in a VB6 listbox control. But it only works when Style = 0, for the Standard ListBox. It does NOT work when Style = 1, for the CheckedListBox.

Is there a way to make it work for Style = 1...?

I thought perhaps there was a deeper level of object hierarchy with the CheckedListBox, such as List1.List(n).Child.Caption or some such thing, but it seems to be the same as the Standard ListBox; the hierarchy stops at List1.List(n) As String. I didn't get anywhere with that line of reasoning.

```
Const LB_SETTABSTOPS = &H192
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Sub SetTab()
    Dim tabstops(1) As Long
    tabstops(0) = VBA.CLng(100)
    SendMessage List1.hwnd, LB_SETTABSTOPS, 1, tabstops(0)
    Me.lstProcedureNames.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: No luck here, you may switch to a grid, for example LynxGrid is my preferred one.